# Recycling Bitmap does not free memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have an `Activity` in a `TabHost` with 3 other activities. Hence, these are always alive (or in "on pause" state).

The first activity has four different images (~250kb each) and they are retrieving a lot of memory (around 80MB. Just to point out, I load the minimum size needed for the screen and I'm using `layout_weight` if that helps), so I want to minimize the amount of memory which is needed.

I already tried to delete the images on the `OnPause` state and set them again on `OnResume`, but I didn't have luck, this is one example of what I was trying to do:

```
 imageView.Drawable.Callback = null;
 ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable).Bitmap.Recycle();
 imageView.Drawable.Dispose();
 imageView.SetImageDrawable(null);
 imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
 GC.Collect();
```

I don't know if deleting the `Bitmap` on `OnPause` is the best strategy, but it should work. I don't understand why the `ImageView` isn't collected by the GC (since there are not external references)

**EDIT**
This is how I'm loading the images. It doesn't work even if I put the images on the xml file. Besides, I don't care this code, I just want to **dispose** the bitmaps.

```
       void SetBackgroundImages(int imageId, int resId, float width, float height) {
        var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(imageId);
        using (var bitmap = DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources, resId, width, height))
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
    public static Bitmap DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, float reqWidth, float reqHeight) {

    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options {InJustDecodeBounds = true};
    using (var b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res,resId,options)){}
        options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you loading your images? Simply telling `ImageView` to stretch or scale the image, does not mean you are loading it with the minimum size possible. Afaik, you also need to `Invalidate` the `ImageView` in order to release the reference to the `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's not the point, but I'm loading the images as Xamarin (and Google) docs points (http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/), getting a sample. I tried to invalidate the ImageView (thanks), but there is not difference, in OnResume I'm getting an OutOfMemmory exception...

Comment: Which parts of it are you using? Please provide the code where you actually load the image into a view.

Comment: I edited the question. I don't understand why you down vote my question, I think it's clear... Anyway thank for to try to help me :)

Comment: You were missing a lot of essential information, even after asking into it. Did you try recycling the bitmap right after assigning it to the imageview?

Comment: I tried, but I'm getting a "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end calling to `java.lang.System.gc()` after deleting the images did the trick.

Comment: It is actually `java.lang.System.gc();`

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1))
    using (var bitmap    = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(
            this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon))
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

i saw this approach in several places, another one is the use of WeakReference to ImageView. These approaches can help GC to collect reference to ImageView properly